# React native application theming

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a question related to React Native.

I have existing application that should be themed and theming should be part of the configurable settings. There should be 3 aspects of such theming: changing colors/theme, changing logo and add custom fonts

I see this is a way that there will be settings view where:

- there will be possibility to upload image, image will be stored in filesystem in ios and android and then used as a brand logo
- there will be multiple settings regarding some primary, secondary, buttons colors as hash values, or maybe some color picker component
- The most complicated stuff is having custom fonts that can be configured by user in setting view of application. Anybody have experience with doing such a thing?

Any thought/suggestions in above points will be helpful. Like links to native libraries for both platform or any tips from more experiences React Native developers

Answer (score 2):

The best ways I see to achieve what you want are :

- Use https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs to access file system so you can easily store and access the logo that the user want. If the image has some size restrictions you could as well store your image Base64 string in AsyncStorage but this is not recommended.
- You can have a kind of theming system by using a global style file that your screens use, the values requested (for example "dark", "light" etc...) can be store in AsyncStorage.
- Do you want the user to be able to use his own personal font ? I don't think this is possible. If you want to have multiple fonts and the user can choose which font will be used in a list for example you can follow this tutorial to install custom fonts : https://medium.com/@kswanie21/custom-fonts-in-react-native-tutorial-for-ios-android-76ceeaa0eb78. Then all you want to do is use your theming system to select the fontFamily that your text elements will be using !

Let me know if I'm not clear enough or you need advices, I recently did what you try to achieve :)